# How do I move some data in a column to a new column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula to split data into new columns. I can do it simply but I want to categorize it.

I.E. I have one column with degree information for each person like:

```
BS 1990; MS 1991; PHD 1992;
Next record:
BS 1999; PHD 2000
```

The data is different for each person with varying numbers of degrees. I want to move all the BS to one new column, all MS to another and PHD to another. I can get the data to split into new columns but not into the right columns, since the data is different for each row.

Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried already and what did you expect it to do that it didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- VBA is acceptable,
- Office 2000 or later (for Split function. If you're using an older version than 2003, tell me so I'll double check that.)
- your format is consistent, with a semicolon separator.

then add this code:

```
Function XLstrtok2(sStr As String, sDesiredDegree As String)
    Dim ss() As String, i As Integer
    sStr = Trim(sStr)
    If Right(sStr, 1) = ";" Then sStr = Left(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
    ss = Split(sStr, ";")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ss)    
        If Left(Trim(ss(i)), Len(sDesiredDegree)) = sDesiredDegree Then XLstrtok2 = Trim(ss(i)): Exit Function    
    Next    
    XLstrtok2 = "--"
End Function
```

And shown below is your spreadsheet and the formulas to put the degrees in different columns to the right of the combined string with the semicolons.

Ensure that your columns are wide enough. If desired, we can add more code at the bottom saying

```
With ActiveSheet.Columns("A:E")
    .AutoFit
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
```

Copy the final column to the right as much as is needed. For example, copy E1:E3 to F1:F3.

Copy the final row down as much as is needed. For example, copy A3:E3 to A4:E4 and type new data in A4.

Of course, inserting a row at the top for proper headings is wise.

Tell me if any of this is unclear. Or if this is acceptable. Pay attention to data input and its consistency (e.g. does it sometimes show PHD and other times Ph.D) in order to determine if additional columns are needed, as shown below for PHD variants.

[image: Expanded spreadsheet]

[image: Expanded formulas]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using the (Control-G?) image icon to insert images, but I'm only getting links, as happened on another post too. Could it be this machine's old version of Firefox? I'm heading to FAQs to try and self answer, but appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("BS",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND("BS",A1),7))
```

and copy down. In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("MS",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND("MS",A1),7))
```

and copy down.  In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("PHD",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND("PHD",A1),8))
```

and copy down:

[image]